# Names of Brahmavadinis in our puranas and vedas

Tags: vedas, puranas, brahman, women

I want to know about exemplary women who realised brahman and became brahamavadinis mentioned in our puranas and vedas. Few names and their short backstory will suffice.

Comment: "Most illustrious" "best" "Great" these are subjective. You should specify wha you mean by those words.There are many such women.

Comment: Got it. I just want this to bring different names of brahmavadinis to the fore as part of answers. Just to see different perspectives.